# How can I find a parent of a dynamic table td?

Tags: jquery

Here's some HTML code:

```js
$("#MyTable").on('click', '.MakeNewTableRow', function() {
  var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  thisRow.after("<tr><td>click me</td></tr>");
  thisRow.next().find("td:first").addClass('ShowTheTDValue');
});

$("#MyTable").on('click', '.ShowTheTDValue', function() {
  alert($(this).parent().find("td:first").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='MyTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='MakeNewTableRow'>whatever</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'll get a javascript error about how `$(this).parent` is not a defined function. I can understand how dynamically-created items aren't part of the DOM and therefore I cannot access the previous table row with a parent() function, but surely there's *some* way to get the data from the table row just above the one that gets created dynamically?

How would I do it? I just need to get the word "whatever" into a javascript variable.

Comment: I changed your code into a snippet and it does seem to work

Comment: That returns "click me," but I want it to return "whatever." Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use $(this).parent().prev().find("td:first").text()`.

By just using parent, you are getting the parent of the element being clicked on. But you actually want the element before the parent of the element being clicked on.

```js
$("#MyTable").on('click', '.MakeNewTableRow', function() {
  var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  thisRow.after("<tr><td>click me</td></tr>");
  thisRow.next().find("td:first").addClass('ShowTheTDValue');
});

$("#MyTable").on('click', '.ShowTheTDValue', function() {
  alert($(this).parent().prev().find("td:first").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='MyTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='MakeNewTableRow'>whatever</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Still gives me an error. Let me see if I can figure out the differences between the code, here...

Comment: OK, I have absolutely no idea what I was doing wrong, but removing some of my test lines and going back to what we have here fixed it. I have no idea what the heck I was mistyping. Thank you!